# Access nested objects in js

Tags: javascript

I have a object like

```
var obj = {
  floorPlan: 'hello',
  dateSpan: {
    from: Sat Feb 21 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0530(IST),
    to: Wed Feb 25 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0530(IST)
  }
};
```

and a string

```
var a = 'dateSpan.to';
```

I want to access 'obj.dateSpan.to' using the variable 'a'.
How can I do it?
please help.

Comment: `var a = obj.dateSpan.to;` ???

Comment: suppose to access obj.floorPlan i can use obj['floorPlan']. Similarly i want to access obj.dateSpan.to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split the string by `.` character and loop through the object until you reach the last part of the split string:

```js
function getValue(str) {
    var val = obj,
        parts = str.split('.');
    while (val[parts[0]]) {
        val = val[parts.shift()]
    }
    return parts.length == 0 ? val : null;
}


var obj = {
    floorPlan: 'hello',
    dateSpan: {
        from: "Sat Feb 21 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0530(IST)",
        to: "Wed Feb 25 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0530(IST)"
    }
};

var a = 'dateSpan.to';

alert(getValue(a));
```